# Is there an example with asp.net 5, mvc 6 api and nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-core

The only examples that i found are with Entity Framework 7 that is compatible with asp.net 5.

i'm not sure is this question should be posted here, but someone can point me where to know about nhibernate support for asp.net vNext.

thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/Adipa-G/AngularSeedOwinWebApiNHibernate

Comment: thank you anyway, but it not seems asp.net 5 project, where is the project.json file?

Answer (score 1):

http://druss.co/2015/04/vnext-use-postgresql-fluent-nhibernate-from-asp-net-5-dnx-on-ubuntu/

I had a few minutes, I've tested it, working fine with SQL2008R2.

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemMap : ClassMap<Item>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        Id(item => item.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(item => item.Name);
        Table("Item");
    }
}

public class ItemContext
{
    public IList<Item> GetAll()
    {
        var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var item = new Item
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Test row"
                };
                session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
                trans.Commit();
            }

            using (session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var items = session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Item)).List<Item>();
                return items;
            }
        }
    }

    private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(c =>
                        c.Database("NHibernateTest")
                            .Server(".\\DEV2008R2")
                            .TrustedConnection()
                    ))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ItemMap>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate should not generally care which version of ASP.Net you use. Your use of NHibernate would be unaffected compared to earlier versions of ASP.Net.

If you're aware of some particular reason it wouldn't work, please add a comment.

Comment: Your answer is not the answer for my question. I just want an example to start a project, I never said that couldn't work with nhibernate, anyway thank you for pointing that.

Comment: I suspect you will have trouble finding a quality example that specific. I suggest looking for any MVC+NHibernate example, and also any ASP.NET MVC 6 example, to compare.